# Double cell border for table (for an entire column)

Tags: tables

Hi what I'm trying to do is getting an "empty" column on a table.

Having an empty row is easy by adding a `\hline` twice. Like here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}  
\hline 
 & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline % <-- extra one giving my an "empty" row
row1 & a & b & c \\ 
\hline 
row2 & d & e & f \\ 
\hline 
row3 & g & h & i \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Is there a way of having the same on a column ? E.g. between "row1" and "a".

I tried to ad an additional `|` on the definition (`\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}`), but the horizontal lines are displayed (due to `\hline` causes a line on the whole width of the table)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}  %<-- change here
\hline 
 & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline 
row1 & a & b & c \\ 
\hline 
row2 & d & e & f \\ 
\hline 
row3 & g & h & i \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

What I want to have is this output, but without the red circled borders (I want to have it like the green one):

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5A]

This is how the column should appear:

[image]

Comment: @TeXnician thx I figures this out to late. its still causing an issue. see the amended questions :)

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: like on the last screenshot but without the "closing" horizontal lines/borders. Like between "row0" and "row1" there are no vertial lines/borders

Comment: just added it ;)

Comment: So if I understand that correctly, you don't want a horizontal lines at those places where there is a vertical one (or only for the doubled), right?

Comment: thx for your patience. I basically want a column that has no horizontal lines. I added an preffered output. hope this helps

Comment: package `hhline`? but better is not have vertical lines at all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `hhline` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}  %<-- change here
  \hhline{-||---}
  & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
  \hhline{=::===}
  row1 & a & b & c \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row2 & d & e & f \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row3 & g & h & i \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]