# Hiding one cell border using hhline package

Tags: tables

I'm having this beautiful answer here  [Double cell border for table (for an entire column)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373337/double-cell-border-for-table-entire-row/373342#373342) using the [hhline](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) package and want to get even further in terms of layout aspects.

The current code by @StefanH is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}  
  \hhline{-||---}
  & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
  \hhline{=::===}
  row1 & a & b & c \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row2 & d & e & f \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row3 & g & h & i \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

but I want to get even further and having the top left cell hidden/without borders so it should look s.th. like this:
[image]

I managed it using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|} 
  \hhline{~|---}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
  \hhline{-::===}
  row1 & a & b & c \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row2 & d & e & f \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row3 & g & h & i \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

But, if you might see, there is an little dot (leftover from the border) which I would like to hide as well:

[image]

any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: more professional look of your table you will obtain with `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
  \toprule
    & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\
  \midrule
  row1 & a & b & c \\
  row2 & d & e & f \\
  row3 & g & h & i \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: well ok, but I think for "my" real data (not this fake entries) it gets a bit unclear due to the amount rows and columns in the table. but thx anyway. Or is there may a way to highlight/seperate the first column as in my example?

Comment: @user2798895 I agree with @Zarko with respect to the table: vertical separators are especially bad to be read and seem unprofessional. I think that, if you want to enhance readability of long tables or possibly single out some column, you could use different shades of grey, with the `colortbl` package

Comment: that is not true. with linnes the table is not more clear ... However, for example after each fith row you can add `\addlinespace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't say what kind of `tabular` looks best, but I will try to help you cover up the unsightly dot.  I did it by adding the line between `row1` and the subsequent `&` separator.  It had to be added there, because it is the 2nd row of code that is laying down that dot in the 1st row.  What I did is lay down a zero-width, `\smash`ed `\rule` that covers up the dot.  I did it in `red!5` so you can see the impact of it.  Change that color to `white` and you are good to go.  The `14pt` may need adjustment depending on the width of the cell contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|} 
  \hhline{~|---}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
  \hhline{-::===}
  row1 
% THE FOLLOWING LINE WAS ADDED, CHANGE red!5 TO white, ALTER 14pt TO SUIT DATA
  \unskip\textcolor{red!5}{\makebox[0pt]{\smash{\rule[12pt]{14pt}{3pt}}}}
%
   & a & b & c \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row2 & d & e & f \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row3 & g & h & i \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternate method is to leave the `tabular` as you had it and `\stackinset` a `\rule` over the complete `tabular`, from the upper left:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline,xcolor,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{}{t}{}{\textcolor{red!5}{\rule{37pt}{16pt}}}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|} 
  \hhline{~|---}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
  \hhline{-::===}
  row1 
   & a & b & c \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row2 & d & e & f \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row3 & g & h & i \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As long as the first row remains a single line, a macro can be set up to help.  In this case, `\coverup{<widest col1 entry>}{<original tabular>}` can be invoked.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline,xcolor,stackengine}
\newcommand\coverup[2]{%
  \stackinset{l}{\fboxrule}{t}{2\fboxrule}{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{red!5}{%
    \kern2\tabcolsep \phantom{#1}\strut}}{\ignorespaces#2\unskip}}
\begin{document}
\coverup{row1}{
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|} 
  \hhline{~|---}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
  \hhline{-::===}
  row1 
   & a & b & c \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row2 & d & e & f \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
  row3 & g & h & i \\ 
  \hhline{-||---}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a brake and see [Less is more](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/). Considering this in design of your table, you can get:

[image]

Is above table really less readable than yours?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}} 
    \toprule 
        & headline1 & headline2 & headline3 \\ 
    \midrule 
row 1   & aaaaaaaa  & bbbbbbbb  & ccccccc   \\ 
row 2   & dddddddd  & eeeeeeee  & ffffffff  \\ 
row 3   & gggggggg  & hhhhhhhh  & iiiiiiii  \\
row 4   & jjjjjjjj  & kkkkkkkk  & llllllll  \\
row 5   & mmmmmmmm  & nnnnnnnn  & oooooooo  \\
    \addlinespace
row 1   & aaaaaaaa  & bbbbbbbb  & ccccccc   \\
row 2   & dddddddd  & eeeeeeee  & ffffffff  \\
row 3   & gggggggg  & hhhhhhhh  & iiiiiiii  \\
row 4   & jjjjjjjj  & kkkkkkkk  & llllllll  \\
row 5   & mmmmmmmm  & nnnnnnnn  & oooooooo  \\
    \addlinespace
row 1   & aaaaaaaa  & bbbbbbbb  & ccccccc   \\
row 2   & dddddddd  & eeeeeeee  & ffffffff  \\
row 3   & gggggggg  & hhhhhhhh  & iiiiiiii  \\
row 4   & jjjjjjjj  & kkkkkkkk  & llllllll  \\
row 5   & mmmmmmmm  & nnnnnnnn  & oooooooo  \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes I agree this sample looks good. But insted of row1-row3 I habe longer text / more than one word. Eg. row1=two line of text; row2=one line of text and row3=three lines of text. Without borders it looks very odd.

Comment: Well, I strongly disagree with you. But, if you like to have ugly table, than I will not try anymore to convince to opposite :) . By the way, do you take a time and look in given link?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other possibilities, a little more decorative:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| >{\columncolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}}l||c|c|c|}
\hhline{~|---|}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{1}{c!{}|}{\cellcolor{PapayaWhip}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{headline1} & headline2 & headline3 \\
  \hhline{->{\arrayrulecolor{white}}t :>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}:>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}===:}
   row1 & a & b & c \\
  \hhline{-||---|}
  row2 & d & e & f \\
  \hhline{-||---|}
  row3 & g & h & i \\
  \hhline{-||---|}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}}l|!{\color{RoyalBlue}\vrule width 0.6pt}c|c|c!{\color{RoyalBlue}\vrule width 0.6pt}}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{1}{c!{\hspace{\dimexpr\doublerulesep + \arrayrulewidth}}}{\cellcolor{PapayaWhip}} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace{-\arrayrulewidth}}c}{headline1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{headline2} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ headline3} \\\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\hhline{-|>{\arrayrulecolor{RoyalBlue}}|---|}
row1 & a & b & c \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{RoyalBlue}}|---|}
  row2 & d & e & f \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{RoyalBlue}}|---|}
 row3 & g & h & i \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{RoyalBlue}}|---|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]